# how to change UI interactively in shinyapp

Tags: r, shiny

I want to let the user interface change interactively from a textarea into a selectInput and back again.

This is what i put in server.r. I use counter1 and counter2 to let shinyapp know which dynamic ui to choose. When hitting the submitbutton there will be added either 1 to counter1 or counter2. That way counter1 and counter2 will be alternately the same or not.

```
 library(shiny)
counter1 <- 1
counter2 <- 0
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$MainAction <- renderUI( {
    dynamicUi()
  })

dynamicUi <- reactive({
if (counter11 == counter2){
counter1 <- counter1 + 1
return(
selectInput("choose","Choose yes or no", choices = c("yes"="yes","no"="no"))
)
}
else {
counter2 <- counter2 + 1
return(  
tags$textarea(id="textfield", rows=8, cols=90, "put your text here")
)
}
})
})
```

And this is what I put in ui.r

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(


headerPanel("My shiny app"),

sidebarPanel(

uiOutput("MainAction"), 
submitButton("action")    

  ),


  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Output", uiOutput("outputaction"))

    )
  )
))
```

The result is that the shinyapp sticks with the textarea. Obviously that's not what I wanted. Does anyone have an idea what's going wrong here? I guess i missed something.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of submitButton, use `actionButton("counter")` and check if `input$counter` is even or odd in `dynamicUi`.

The reason your code did not work was because reactive expressions like `dynamicUi` only execute when a reactive value (or another reactive expression, or some other reactive thing like `invalidateLater`) that they read causes reactivity to be triggered. In this case `dynamicUI` does not read any reactive value so it won't execute more than once. But if you use `actionButton("counter")` and read `input$counter` then whenever `input$counter` changes the reactive expression will re-execute.

Comment: Thanks Joe! I made it work now. I guess I was too focused on why my 'solution' didn't work.